# How to find the local network Ip address

Tags: vb.net

I have a .net network application , and as part of improving the performance of the software i would like to find the shortest route to the server . When i have more than one network , i need to find the local network ip from these current ip list .

Please help ,i am working in Vb.net

Comment: Which one? PCs can have more than one network card, and even individual network cards can have more than one address.  Moreover, it's common now in many environments to have both wifi and wired connections active on the same network, or have virtual network adapters for features like a virtual machine hypervisor or virtual wireless access points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the article at:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

You will note that the network adapter in the range:
192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255

OR
172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255

OR
10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255

indicate that the IP in these ranges is on a local network....

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/bafd4d0c-1b05-4974-aff8-7cc523f61fe9) this will show you how to get the network name and then from that you can determine the local network name. This is based on the principle that the local network is always local area network or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following steps to find local network IP address.

First you configure IP for your machine,

Goto->Start->Run->ncpa.cpl->right click on Local area connection->click on properties->click on Internet protocol->click properties->give IP address like '192.168.0.2'.

Or other format

start->Run->cmd->cd->ipconfig

then showing the ip address.